# Create all possible geom_col charts of the dataset using rowwise and rlang

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr, rlang

I want to create and save all the possible geom_col charts of a dataset with categorical variables on Y axis and average (grouping variable being y) value of numeric variables on x axis.

I borrowed ideas from [this](http://%20https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/294422_099df24a1c0f46f99db848ca5c48ff6b.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65597281/how-to-supply-variable-names-as-strings-in-fct-reorder-within-ggplot-code/65597533?noredirect=1#comment115985180_65597533) link and created the following code, but struggling to make it work. Please advise.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(skimr)

cat_vars <- skim(mpg) %>% as.data.frame() %>% filter(skim_type == "character", character.n_unique <= 16) %>% pull(skim_variable) 

num_vars <- skim(mpg) %>% as.data.frame() %>% filter(skim_type == "numeric") %>% pull(skim_variable)

vars <- cross_df(list(y= cat_vars, x = num_vars))

plots <- bind_rows(rep(list(mpg), nrow(vars)), .id = "grp") %>%
  nest_by(grp) %>%
  bind_cols(vars) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(plot = list(~(data %>%
                         group_by(y) %>%
                         summarise("{x}" = mean(.data[[x]], na.rm = T)) %>%
                         ungroup()) %>%
                       ggplot() +
                       geom_col(aes(x = .data[[x]],
                                    y = fct_reorder(.data[[y]], .data[[x]], .fun = sum, na.rm = T),
                                    fill = .data[[y]]), width = 0.8) +
                       xlab(paste0("Avg. ", x)) +
                       ylab(y) +
                       theme_classic()))),
filename = paste0(x, "_by_", y, ".pdf")) %>%
  select(filename, plot)

pwalk(plots, ggsave, path =  getwd())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to `bind_row`s, `nest`, ... Instead:

1. Put your plotting code in a helper function instead of wrapping everything in a pipeline. This allows for much easier debugging as well as cleaner and clearer code.
2. Use map2 to loop over the columns of your df `vars`
3. One issue with your code was `summarise("{x}" = mean(.data[[x]], na.rm = T))` which will create a variable named `{x}`. Instead use e.g. `!!sym(x) := ...` to assign the value back to `x` if `x` is a string.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(skimr)

cat_vars <- skim(mpg) %>% as.data.frame() %>% filter(skim_type == "character", character.n_unique <= 16) %>% pull(skim_variable) 

num_vars <- skim(mpg) %>% as.data.frame() %>% filter(skim_type == "numeric") %>% pull(skim_variable)

vars <- cross_df(list(y= cat_vars, x = num_vars))

make_plot <- function(data, x, y) {
  data <- data %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(y))) %>%
    summarise(!!sym(x) := mean(.data[[x]], na.rm = T), .groups = "drop") %>%
    ungroup()
  
  ggplot(data) +
    geom_col(aes(x = .data[[x]],
                 y = fct_reorder(.data[[y]], .data[[x]], .fun = sum, na.rm = T),
                 fill = .data[[y]]), width = 0.8) +
    xlab(paste0("Avg. ", x)) +
    ylab(y) +
    theme_classic()
}

plots <- map2(vars$x, vars$y, make_plot, data = mpg)

length(plots)
#> [1] 25

plots[[1]]

# Export

pwalk(list(x = vars$x, y = vars$y, p = plots), function(x, y, p) ggsave(filename = paste0(x, "_by_", y, ".pdf"), plot = p, path =  getwd()))
```

[image]

Comment: Great!! It works. I am always confused between the {{}}, !!sym, .data[[]] operators. I thought everything now a days can be handled using curly curly operator!

Comment: Yep. I'm also not calling me an expert in these matters. But: Use Curly-Curly when you pass variables without quotes. If you pass variables as strings  then make use of `.data`. However, if you want to use a variable passed as string on the LHS, i.e. if you want to assign a value to this var then use of !!sym(). (:

Comment: That sounds perfect! Thanks!